# Calculate Library Fine (PHP)

Tags: php

So, here is the question (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/library-fine) I am trying to solve. To solve this, I created a simple function `calculateFine` and set the conditions to calculate the fine. What's the problem, then? Well, when I run the code on my machine, everything seems fine, but hackerrank won't accept the code. I am new to PHP and concept of functions was a bit confusing for me, but I tried. Below is my code:

```
<?php
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

$_a = explode(" ",fgets($_fp));
$_b = explode(" ",fgets($_fp));

// Initialising variable
$_fine = "";

// Calling Function
calculateFine($_a,$_b);

// Defining Function
function calculateFine($actualDate, $returnDate) 
    { 

        // Checking various conditions

        if ($actualDate[0] <= $returnDate[0] && $actualDate[1] == $returnDate[1] && $actualDate[2] == $returnDate[2])  
            {
                $_fine = 0;
                echo $_fine;
            }
        elseif($actualDate[0] > $returnDate[0] && $actualDate[1] == $returnDate[1] && $actualDate[2] == $returnDate[2])
            {
                $_late = $actualDate[0] - $returnDate[0];
                $_fine = 15*$_late;
                echo $_fine;
            }
        elseif($actualDate[1] > $returnDate[1] && $actualDate[2] == $returnDate[2])
            {
                $_late = $actualDate[1] - $returnDate[1];
                $_fine = 500*$_late;
                echo $_fine;
            }
        elseif($actualDate[2] > $returnDate[2])     
            {
                $_fine = 10000;
                echo $_fine;
            }
        else 
            { 
                $_fine = 0;
                echo $fine;  // Updated (This is the undefined variable causing error )
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: When creating a function like this, it is often better to have the function return the value. So in your first `if` statement, you could simply put `return 0`, and so on for the other conditions. Then you could just echo the output of your function like so: `echo calculateFine($_a,$_b);`. This also results in not having to initialize the $_fine variable.

Comment: @Thijis tried this, but the compiler (at HackerRank) showed wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, sorry for the carelessness. The last echo is `$fine` instead of `$_fine`. That's why the condition was not matching with some of the test cases. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a newline in `$actualDate[2]`. So if you trim it you'll get the right answer:

```
trim($actualDate[2])
```

But would be better to trim it here already:

```
$_a = explode(" ",trim(fgets($_fp)));
$_b = explode(" ",trim(fgets($_fp)));
```

Comment: Hi,This helped in passing most of the test cases, but some cases didn't passed, like on of them being, `$_a = 28 2 2015` and `$_b = 15 4 2015` which should output 0. (I got the output 0 on my machine, but not on HR)

Comment: Thankyou. It was an syntax error. (Undefined variable `$fine` in last line)